# Two foreign keys reference the primary key of another table

Tags: sql

So I have two tables

```
Person(personID, first_name, last_name);
Relation(relationID, child_personID, parent_personID);
```

personID and relationID are both primary keys. child_personID and parent_personID are both foreign keys.

I want to make a query so I have the first names and last names of both the child and parent.

child.first_name child.last_name and parent.first_name, parent.last_name

Comment: You might want to correct your title, it's misleading, since we're not talking about foreign keys here.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you have any other table where child's data is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about this is using [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [table aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29). Something like this:

```
select
    child.first_name,
    child.last_name,
    parent.first_name,
    parent.last_name
from relation r
    join person child on r.child_personID = child.id
    join person parent on r.parent_personID = parent.id
```